# RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Name'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to MVC C# application. I'm Sending a student Object from Controller to View. The Student class is defined in the Model. here is the code for Controller class. StudentController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcApplication.Models;

namespace MvcApplication.Controllers
{
   public class StudentController : Controller
   {
       //
       // GET: /Student/

       public ViewResult Get()
       {
           Student s = new Student();
            s.Name = "Ali";
            s.SID = "45";            
            return View(s);
       }
   }
}
```

Her is my Model class Student.cs

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MvcApplication.Models
{
    class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my View class get.cshtml

```
@{
     ViewBag.Title = "get";
 }

 <h2>get</h2>
 <p> @Model.Name </p>
 <p> @Model.SID </p>
```

When I hit the request at http://localhost:16206/Student/get
following exception occur.

```
RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Name'
```

Don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Was my answer correct? Has it helper you somehow?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the declaration of the model at the top of your page:

```
@model MvcApplication.Models.Student
@{
     ViewBag.Title = "get";
 }
...
```

Also, you might want to declare your `Student` model `public`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically in ASP.MVC you have three ways to pass information from a controller to a view. You can use:

- ViewBag
- Dynamic views
- Strongly typed views

Middle option is used seldom, but I think it's always worth to know. In your case it would look as follows:

```
@model dynamic

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "get";
}

<h2>get</h2>
<p> @Model.Name </p>
<p> @Model.SID </p>
```

On the other hand strongly typed view looks as Omri mentioned:

```
@model MvcApplication.Models.Student
@{
     ViewBag.Title = "get";
}

<h2>get</h2>
<p> @Model.Name </p>
<p> @Model.SID </p>
```

Also as Omri mentioned - very important thing is a model class should be public:

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MvcApplication.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As I wrote you can also use ViewBag instead of model. Then it would look like as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcApplication.Models;

namespace MvcApplication.Controllers
{
   public class StudentController : Controller
   {
       //
       // GET: /Student/

       public ViewResult Get()
       {
            ViewBag.Name = "Ali";
            ViewBag.SID = "45";            
            return View();
       }
   }
}
```

And view:

```
@{
     ViewBag.Title = "get";
}

<h2>get</h2>
<p> @ViewBag.Name </p>
<p> @ViewBag.SID </p>
```

There are more options like ViewData, TempData. You can read about it here:

- http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/differences-between-viewdata-viewbag-session-and-tempdata
- http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/9KHW190712-ViewData-vs-ViewBag-vs-TempData-vs-Session.html